# Convert string to big endian, index out of range

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to convert a string to a big endian but due to my lack of experience with bit shifting etc, I've got stuck with the following so far:

```
def my_func(self, b):
    a = [(len(b)+3) >> 2]

    for i, val in enumerate(b):
        a[i>>2] |= ord(b[i]) << (24-(i & 3)*8)
    return a
```

The above returns the error
 `a[i>>2] |= ord(b[i]) << (24-(i & 3)*8)
IndexError: list index out of range`, and also never gets further through the loop index than #4.

The error message is pointing to the a[] list.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? I'm porting this from JavaScript so that may be the issue (link to that http://pastebin.com/GKE3AeCm )

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're doing this by hand? The [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module can do this for you.

Comment: @Mike I did attempt using the struct module, but after a few hours and various type errors gave up.

Comment: I see. Also, what python data type are you trying to convert to?

Comment: @Mike output from this function needs to be an array/list. e.g. input='pass123', output='1885434739,825373440'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without resorting to other methods, your code just needs to be adjusted more correctly from the Javascript version. In Javascript you are creating an `Array` of certain length, but in your Python code you always create a list of size 1. Here is it corrected:

```
def my_func(b):
    a = [0] * ((len(b)+3) >> 2)

    for i, val in enumerate(b):
        a[i>>2] |= ord(b[i]) << (24-(i & 3)*8)
    return a
```

So what you are doing is considering sequences of 4 objects as being raw bytes and unpacking them to build an integer. Using `struct`, the correct way would be to be explicit about your data being bytes and passing it as such:

```
import struct

def my_func2(data):
    lb = len(data)
    if lb % 4:
        data += b'\x00' * (4 - (lb % 4))
    a = [struct.unpack('>i', data[i:i+4])[0] for i in range(0, lb, 4)]
    return a

print(my_func2(b'pass123'))
```

Comment: Urgh so simple. Definitely a case of staring at the same block of code too long and turning into a fool. ___

Comment: @keekers also consider using `struct.unpack` for the task.

Comment: gave your unpack method a try, resulted in _TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface_ on the second to last time though

Comment: @keekers I wasn't aware you were using Python 3. In that case, the correct way is to pass bytes to the function, remove `b = ''.join(b)` and change `b += '....'` to `b += b'....'`.

Comment: Thanks, yes im using 3.2, did as you said but another error. `b += b'\x00' * (4 - (lb % 4))` the message being _Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly_

Comment: @keekers you are not passing bytes to the function then. See the exact example in the answer.